# Print vs Screen layout in Zend Framework

Tags: css, zend-framework, layout, printing

I am using a 'skins' approach to loading css into my Zend Framework site.

**From layout.phtml:**

```
  <head>
  <?php 
    print $this->headTitle();
    print $this->headScript();
    $this->loadSkin($this->skin);
    print $this->headLink();
    print $this->jQuery();
    print $this->layout()->customJS;
  ?>
</head>
```

where **loadSkin()** is a view helper that looks like this:

```
class Zend_View_Helper_LoadSkin extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {
  public function loadSkin ($skin) {
    $skinData = new Zend_Config_Xml('./skins/' . $skin . '/skin.xml');
    $stylesheets = $skinData->stylesheets->stylesheet->toArray();
    if (is_array($stylesheets)) {
      foreach ($stylesheets as $stylesheet) {
        $this->view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('$skin.'/css/'.$stylesheet);
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Everything shows up fine in the browser (any graphical browser), including jQueryUI elements, like here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/70PVl.png.

But when I print, the css is completely ignored, like here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGC25.png.

I am completely stumped - and can't find anything here or on ZF forums about giving separate css parameters for printing. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
-Roman

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iam not sure, but i think you have to set the MediaType for the CSS File:

```
//Display + Print
->appendStylesheet($skin.'/css/'.$stylesheet, 'screen,print');

//Only for Printers
->appendStylesheet($skin.'/css/'.$stylesheet, 'print');
```

View the following link for more information about the View-Helper for Stylesheets http://framework.zend.com/manual/de/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headlink

Comment: This is correct. If the last argument is not set the generated code will default to media="screen", and thus there will be no css for print.

Answer (score 0):

Try `setStylesheet()` method to add style sheet.